# Emit SwiftSupport directory for Ad Hoc builds

Tags: app-store, xcodebuild

Is there a way to generate the SwiftSupport directory in Ad-hoc builds, i.e. without method=app-store in exportOptions.plist?

We build developer-signed .ipas for internal testing, then resign them with a distribution certificate before uploading to App Store Connect. But the ad-hoc builds do not contain the SwiftSupport directory, causing Apple to reject the package.

So, setting `method` to `app-store` produces `SwiftSupport`, but requires a distribution certificate, which the CI builder doesn't have. Is there any other way to instruct xcodebuild to generate this directory?

Answer (score 0):

The SwiftSupport directory is inside the `.xcarchive` directory. Assuming your ipa and xcarchive are in the `build/Applications` directory, you can add the missing SwiftSupport directory to the ipa like so:

```
pushd build/Applications/myapp.xcarchive
zip -r ../myapp.ipa SwiftSupport
popd
```

This adds SwiftSupport at the root of the ipa archive. If you try to run something like `zip -r myapp.ipa myapp.xcarchive/SwiftSupport`, you'll get an extra myapp.xcarchive subdirectory.